# UDP with gso doesn't receive the entire message

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, udp

I am trying to use UDP with GSO (Generic Segmentation Offload) to send 50Kb sized packets.

```
// sender side 
int val = 1472; // ETHERNET - udp - upv4 header
if (setsockopt(fdt, SOL_UDP, UDP_SEGMENT, &val, sizeof(val)))
    error(1, errno, "setsockopt udp segment");
int ret = sendmsg(fd, msg, flags);
```

and on the recv size, I do

```
// recv side 
int ret = recvmsg(fd, msg, flags);
```

I can see that I send 50Kb message and receiver side only received 1472 with one call. I have heard about GRO (Generic Receive Offload) but I didn't find any example online. Do I have to make multiple syscalls to get all the data, is it possible to set a socket option or make a syscall to receive reassembled message in one go? How can it be more efficient if I have to make multiple system calls instead of just relying on IP fragmentation and sending larger than MTU packets?

Comment: Sending over-sized UDP packets is not something I'd trust, especially with how many layers of NAT and stateful firewalls you're likely to have in the middle. Can't you just carve that transmission up into smaller chunks or use TCP to stream it?

Comment: As a note 1472 (ish) is about what you'd expect for the first packet of a fragmented packet sequence.

Comment: @tadman: I am sure that one recvmsg only received 1472 of the first packet in a sequence of fragmented message, I think UDP GRO is supposed to reassemble all the fragmented packets and return the whole message.

Comment: @tadman: also, data is transferred over ethernet between to ECUs directly connected. no rerouting, NAT or anything. 1472 is pretty much the largest safe packet we can send.

Comment: @tadman: we are currently using TCP, but we have we are trying UDP for better latency.

Comment: How large is your socket receive buffer? and how large your application's receive buffer?

Comment: UDP datagrams are ideally around 576 octets, and you _never_ want to send datagrams that result in packets larger than your path MTU (you can use PMTUD to discover the smallest MTU in the path). You _will_ lose datagrams, and the smaller they are, the less you will lose. Also, smart sites now have firewalls drop packet fragments (the first goes through, but the rest of the fragments are dropped) in order to prevent fragmentation attacks.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne (1 << 27) for socket rcv buffer and application buffer is twice as large as the size of the message

Comment: If you want low-latency messaging then rolling your own UDP-esqpe protocol is not likely to be fun nor rewarding. Why not look at something like [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org) first which is geared towards extremely low latency and high throughput?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/358910/) you can read for deep understand GSO and GRO. **Ethtool may be able to enable/disable GRO on specific interfaces. Depends on the version.** If you can go well with it, then it's best.

If not, since the Linux network stack is realy complicated, it's hard to check which part makes the segment fail just by the result. I think it's better to use some tools like netstat, ss, sar, tcpdump, wireshark and others to analyze each layer and then it's much easier to know where is wrong. But don't forget to check if your hardware support this.